# Accessing object reference of a row in a trigger after insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a problem with SQL Object (ORACLE). :(

I have an abstract type Forum, generalized in ForumCategory, and a type Category :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Forum_t AS OBJECT
(
    moderators Users_table_ref,
    topics Topics_table,
    MEMBER FUNCTION getName RETURN VARCHAR2
)
NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;
/

CREATE TABLE Forum OF Forum_t
NESTED TABLE moderators STORE AS Liste_moderators,
NESTED TABLE topics STORE AS Liste_topics
    (NESTED TABLE posts STORE AS Liste_posts);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ForumCategory_t UNDER Forum_t
(
    category REF Category_t,
    OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION getName RETURN VARCHAR2
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY ForumCategory_t AS
    OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION getName RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
        c Category_t;
    BEGIN
        SELECT DEREF(SELF.category) INTO c FROM DUAL;
        RETURN c.name;
    END getName; 
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Category_t AS OBJECT
(
    name VARCHAR2(60)
);
/

CREATE TABLE Category OF Category_t
(
    CONSTRAINT PK_CAT_NAME PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

I want to make a trigger after insert on table Category which insert a ForumCategory_t on table Forum.

I have this code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Category_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON Category
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ref_cat REF Category_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT REF(c) INTO ref_cat 
    FROM Category c 
    WHERE c.name = :NEW.name; 

    INSERT INTO Forum VALUES(ForumCategory_t(Users_table_ref(),Topics_table(),ref_cat));
END;
/
```

The beginning don't work, I cannot select REF of the inserted Category (it's work outside the trigger).

Please, I need help ^^

PS : Sorry for my english

Comment: How is `Users_table_ref` defined; you haven't shown that? Or `Topics_table`.

Comment: Your model has a cyclic dependency: `Category.forum`->`Forum.ref()` and `Forum(ForumCategory).category`->`Category.ref()`.  Cyclic dependencies are bad practice in both relational and object-oriented paradigms.

Comment: @AlexPoole Users_table_ref is a nested table of REF User and Topics_table is a nested table or Topics.

Comment: @APC I thought it will be convenient to access objects in both ways, but you're right, is a bad practice... I update my example, but the problem is always here, I cannot use a trigger on insert on table Category to automatically create a forum and give him a reference to the inserted object...